# Arcpy UpdateCursor not updating field

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update

I have a File Geodatabase Table(no geometry). I am trying to update the last column, called S_Name from concatenated values from other fields.
I am going to write out my logic so it is clear what I want to accomplish

if the PRE_TYPE field is not Null and the SUF_TYPE field is null then update S_Name to the values of PRE_TYPE+NAME+SUF_MOD

if PRE_TYPE is Null and SUF_TYPE is Not Null then update S_Name
to NAME+SUF_TYPE

[image]

Here is my code below. I am pretty sure the logic is sound. The script runs with no errors but does not print bah, and does not update the table.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:path\\Tran_road_NJ.gdb"
layer = "C:path\\Tran_road_NJ.gdb\\Tran_road_geocode_NJ_1"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(layer, ['PRE_TYPE','NAME','SUF_TYPE','SUF_MOD','S_Name']) as rd:
    for x in rd:
        if x[0] != None and x[1] != None and x[2] == None:
            bah = x[0]+' '+x[1] +' '+x[3]
            x[4] = str(bah)
            print bah
            rd.updateRow(x)
        elif x[0] == None and x[1] != None and x[2] != None:
            bah = x[1]+' '+x[2]
            x[4] = str(bah)
            print bah
            rd.updateRow(x)
```

Comment: The cells with no values are probably just empty strings and not None.  Check the value in them and try x[0] != "" or " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brian mentioned in his comment, the table most likely contains empty strings rather than nulls.  Try this code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:path\\Tran_road_NJ.gdb"
layer = "C:path\\Tran_road_NJ.gdb\\Tran_road_geocode_NJ_1"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(layer, ['PRE_TYPE','NAME','SUF_TYPE','SUF_MOD','S_Name']) as rd:
    for x in rd:
        if all([x[0], x[1]]) and (x[2] == None or not str(x[2]).strip()):
            bah = ' '.join(x[:2] + [x[3]])
            x[4] = bah
            print bah
            rd.updateRow(x)
        elif all([x[1], x[2]]) and (x[0] == None or not str(x[0]).strip()):
            bah = ' '.join(x[1:3])
            x[4] = bah
            print bah
            rd.updateRow(x)
```

Comment: very nice, I have never seen the all function. It just checks whether or not the items places in the function exist?

Comment: The [all()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function will evaluate that all conditions in a list are `True`.  So basically like using `and`.  On the contrary, the [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function evaluates if one or more conditions are `True`.  Empty strings and `NoneType`s can be considered `falsy` values, so I'm not explicitly testing.